ASP.NET Identity - Integrating with Magic Links
In the current project we have been using Identity Framework for authorizing and authenticating user into an ASP.NET MVC app.
I have been looking into integrating the authentication with 'Magic Links'. I have a provider that works and is able to provide authentication via email links.
My issue is trying to integrate the solution with the existing Identity Framework and whether it would be possible. I have attempted to perform some checks before an email gets sent however I can't there does isn't a public function within SignInManager to check that a user with that email exists and or then how to link it with the authorization for that account.
Is it worth trying find a way to modify the SignInManager to add in these functions or would this solution just not support Magic Link authentication.
I have tried finding ways to modify the SignInManager or other methods to hook into the API which has been fruitless.
I understand that Identity is locked down for obvious reasons but I would like to find a solution that doesn't involve having to port the entire app identity management to another solution.
Any other suggestions are welcome.
